# WSO2 EMM Configuration Platform settings error

Tags: wso2-iot

While configuring the Android Platform settings with GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) as the mode of communication, I am getting this error in my console after I press the save option:

```
[2016-11-28 09:37:06,888] ERROR {api/invoker-api.jag} -  Exception occurred while accessing sevices org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: < (/emm/modules/backend-service-invoker.js#80)
```

Also on the emm console dashboard, the following is printed:

```
An unexpected error occurred
```

Comment: What was the EMM product version you have used ?

Comment: thanks sir but the error has been sorted out now